# Entity Framework - Update Error - The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value is already being tracked

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We are currently working with Entity Framework and SQLite. In our scenario we have

1. Multiple worker threads
2. No composition pattern (because of governance reasons)
3. We are creating a new `DbContext` for every single database transaction.

Sample code:

```
public int Update(IEnumerable<MyChanges> changes)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
    { 
        dbContext.TypeChanges.UpdateRange(changes);  // <-- Exception
        return dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The "already tracked entity" is a shared member instance in form of:

`ChangeA.Child` is the same as `ChangeB.Child`. The exception occurs for this child, which is already existant in the DB and not modified. Other threads also work with this child instance.

In this very small function we get an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type <type> cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value <primaryKey> is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Note: The primary key is a string value and not auto-generated

I can't understand what is going wrong.

My guess is: a different thread is currently also tracking the instance (which is likely in our setup) and the entity is not allowed to be tracked in multiple threads, even if they use different instances of `MyDbContext`.

But if that isn't allowed, how can you ever have multiple threads working on your data? Data structures are always deep and own each other.

Question: is there any way to track an entity in multiple threads (different contexts) and just let the last transaction win? This would be totally sufficient for us.

Thanks for every little hint. I am stuck at this point for a really long time now. I think, I misunderstood  some basic concept of the EF completely.

Best regards,
Tailor

1. Locks/monitors with a singleton `DbContext` (works, but is slow and not a sophisticated solution)
2. Checking the tracked entities (which are empty in my example)
3. Using Add/Attach - same error

Comment: Check for duplicates in `changes`. If you create `DbContext` and and then dispose, there should not be any multithreading issues. OR `changes` is mutable collection and other threads put duplicates at the same time. Change signature of your method to `Update(IReadOnlyCollection<MyChanges> changes)` and correct compilation issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

1, There are no duplicates in `changes`.
2. Every change is related to another object. This object is already in the database and every change is related to the SAME instance. This instance throws the exception. Also other threads work with this instance.

Comment: Also I added a short explanation for the object structure to the question.

Comment: This exception is clear: you have attached entity with the same Primary Key. How you did that - miracle. `DbContext` do not share its `ChangeTracker` between instances. As I remember also EF checks for existence by object reference, maybe it is your case.

Comment: *ChangeA.Child is the same as ChangeB.Child* if they have different object references, yes you may have issue. Clear references before update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one problem with passing entities around outside of the scope of the DbContext that created them. This error commonly occurs when using an entity as a DTO/ViewModel where it is sent back to a Controller, especially when dealing with object graphs. (entities containing related entities) When working with entities, References are everything, and things like serialization and re-composition will break this. Loading data with `AsNoTracking()` can also cause this issue if you go to re-attach the detached entity graphs.

Let's take an example where we load two orders for a customer and each order references a Status lookup entity.

```
Order ID 1 -> Status "Open"
Order ID 2 -> Status "Shipped"
```

Now we send the customer and it's orders to be updated. Behind the scenes we would have code, or rely on EF to figure out and do roughly the following:

- `Attach` Ofder ID 1
- `Attach` Status "Open"
- Set Order ID 1 State to Modified
- `Attach` Ofder ID 2
- `Attach` Status "Shipped"
- Set Order ID 2 State to Modified
- `SaveChanges()`

... and everything seems to work fine. Then we get to the next customer, again they have 2 orders, but both are "Open":

```
Order ID 3 -> Status "Open"
Order ID 4 -> Status "Open"
```

- `Attach` Ofder ID 3
- `Attach` Status "Open"
- Set Order ID 1 State to Modified
- `Attach` Ofder ID 4
- `Attach` Status "Open"
- !! Exception !!

If we look a little deeper with the references you can see what is going on. When we read the data from EF, in the first case we would see something like:

```
Order ID 1 -> Status "Open" (Reference A)
Order ID 2 -> Status "Shipped" (Reference B)
```

and in the second case:

```
Order ID 3 -> Status "Open" (Reference A)
Order ID 4 -> Status "Open" (Reference A)
```

When EF loaded the Orders where multiple orders point to the same related entity, they will both point to the same reference to that tracked entity. You can verify this using `object.ReferenceEquals(order3.Status, order4.Status);`

Now the problem comes when you attempt to de-serialize entities or they get re-composed such as in a controller Form POST operation. What we get for Order 3 & 4 would be:

```
Order ID 3 -> Status "Open" (Reference D)
Order ID 4 -> Status "Open" (Reference E)
```

The call to `object.ReferenceEquals(order3.Status, order4.Status);` will return `false`. We attach Order 3's Status so the DbContext is tracking a status with a key of "Open", but then when we go to attach Order 4's status, "Open" is already tracked.

When you want to attach entities to a DbContext, you should always check the tracking cache first, then attach if an instance isn't tracked or replace the reference(s) to tracked entities if they are. So looking at the saving orders example, we need to modify that a bit:

- `Attach` Ofder ID 3
- Check tracking cache (`.Local`) for Status "Open"

  - If found, replace reference with existing status
  - If not found, `Attach` Status "Open"
- Set Order ID 1 State to Modified
- `Attach` Ofder ID 4
- Check tracking cache (`.Local`) for Status "Open"

  - If found, replace reference with existing status
  - If not found, `Attach` Status "Open"
- Set Order ID 2 State to Modified
- `SaveChanges()`

So in code something like:

```
foreach (var order in orders)
{
    if(_context.Orders.Local.Any(o => o.Id == order.Id)
        throw new InvalidOperation("Somehow an order was already loaded/updated, duplicate reference.");
    var existingStatus = _context.Statuses.Local.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == order.Status.Id);
    if (existingStatus != null)
         order.Status = existingStatus;
    else
         _context.Attach(order.Status);

    _context.Attach(order);
    _context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Personally I do not recommend sending detached entities outside of the scope of the DbContext they were read. While it may look simpler than creating a dedicated DTO/ViewModel it poses complications like the above scenario, results in larger blocks of unnecessary data being passed around, leads to issues where re-composition doesn't contain enough information resulting in unintentional edits or errors, risks exposing too much detail about the internals of your system to 3rd parties, risks unintended manipulation due to bugs or malicious actors, and risks significant performance issues if using lazy loading.

But if using detached entities you need to always check for tracked references before attaching any entity and handle that scenario.

Comment: This answer helped me very much! In reality the case was even more complicated, but bottom line:

There was a deep structure of members and deep down a reference got cloned (with same values), so in the data structure of a single change I had two references to an object with same primary key and different reference (didn't matter that all values were the same).

Thank you, your answer motivated me to dig deeper into the data structure and find the root cause.

Comment: After fixing everything and thinking about it: Can you briefly explain, **why** it is done this was? In my opinion only the primary key should matter, not the object reference. If all values are equal, everything should work as normal.

In our application it is nearly impossible to guarantee same references everywhere. Some things get newly created, some get fetched from DB, they get merged and hold a lot of different objects in a huge structure of DB entries.

For me, it's a pain to care about the "same reference".

Comment: Mainly because at the end of the day a tracked entity is a representation of a row in a database. When EF is given two entities that each reference the same related entity it doesn't restrict changes to "owned" type relationships vs. just merely sharing a  reference. The error is telling you that you need to be explicit and cannot have two copies of the same db row being tracked. It's not going to just pick one behind the scenes and replace references. This is the main reason I do not recommend using entities for data transport. Sadly so many examples steer developers into doing just that.

Answer (score 1):

The DBContext is not thread safe. If you want to work on the same Database on multiple threads you have to create multiple DBContext instances. One DBContext should only be used for one unit of work e.g. everything that happends if you click a button on the UI (one transaction).

If you require multi threading in your function you should think about doing the calculations in parallel and saving everything to the database at once on the same thread. If the data does not have to be saved in the same transaction just spin up a new DBContext everytime you need it.

If that is not the issue did you check if every entity in *changes* has a different primary key?